# How use jinja2 variable inside ansible inventory

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, jinja2

I have test varibale defined in ansible inventory:

```
test: 'some string'
```

and jinja2 template where this variable placed as {{ test }}.
After jinja2 worked, I get:

```
u'some string'
```

inside my template...

In case I set test variable as int:

```
test: 10000
```

I get:

```
 u'10000'
```

I've tried different filters but it failed.
Is it possible to get original value inside my output?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know the `test` variable will always return a number.  If so, when you reference the variable you can cast it as an `int` like this:

```
 - debug:
     msg: "The value of test is {{ test | int }}"
```

Answer (score -1):

**Option A**

Convert in python like so

```
return render_template('my.html', myvar=int('1000'))
```

**Option B**

Convert in in the template using `| int` like so

```
{{ myvar | int }}
```